# Azure text to speech convert SpeakTextAsync to valid NAudio wavestream

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.1, synthesizer

I am trying to use the Azure text to Speech service (Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech) to convert text to audio, and then convert the audio to another format using NAudio.

I already got the NAudio part working using an mp3 file. But I cannot get any output from `SpeakTextAsync` that will work with NAudio.

**This is the code where I try to play the file using NAudio (as temperary test), but this doesn't play anything valid.**

```
var waveStream = new RawSourceWaveStream(azureStream, new WaveFormat());
using (var waveOut = new WaveOutEvent())
{
    waveOut.Init(waveStream);
    Log.Logger.Debug("Playing sounds...");
    waveOut.Play();
    while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

The 2 possible outputs I found are, but I am probably missing something important:

**Option 1 (AudioDataStream):**

```
using var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(_config, null);
using var result = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);
switch (result.Reason)
{
    case ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
        Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesized to speaker for text [{text}]");
        return AudioDataStream.FromResult(result);
    case ResultReason.Canceled:
    {
         var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
         Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");

         if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
         {
             Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
             Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
         }
         return null;
     }
     default:
         return null;
 }
```

**Option 2 (PullAudioOutputStream):**

```
PullAudioOutputStream stream = new PullAudioOutputStream();
AudioConfig config = AudioConfig.FromStreamOutput(stream);

using var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(_config, null);
using var result = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);
switch (result.Reason)
{
    case ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
        Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesized to speaker for text [{text}]");
        return stream;
    case ResultReason.Canceled:
    {
         var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
         Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");

         if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
         {
             Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
             Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
         }
         return null;
     }
     default:
         return null;
 }
```

So how to I convert the text to speech to a valid NAudio format?

Comment: Are you getting something from  `await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);` ?

Comment: @abestrad Yes I get the result. The code is working, but I have no way to go to an audio type that exists in NAudio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin,

Why do you need NAudio for ? if it's for playback only, it's not necessary, the following line play the text out loud :

```
await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);
```

For any other reason, If you need the result of speech synthesis with NAudio.

```
if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
{
    using var stream = new MemoryStream(result.AudioData);
    using var reader = new WaveFileReader(stream);
    using var player = new WaveOutEvent();

    player.Init(reader);
    player.Play();

    while (player.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
    {

        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, long time. Indeed it is not for playback only. So the temorary file solution is something also thought off, but I wanted to find a way to remove the step of the temporary file. And immediatly go to a stream if that is possible.

Comment: If it is not possible to remove the overhead of creating a temporary file, I will do it this way...

Comment: Hey, long time indeed, a temp file is not mandatory, you can use a memory stream, I've edited my response, it should work.